# Can't create MemoryStream

Tags: c#, memorystream

Is there any reason why this code shouldn't produce a memory stream with the word Slappy in it?

```
    private MemoryStream StringBuilderToMemoryStream(StringBuilder source)
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
        streamWriter.Write("slappy");
        return memoryStream;
    }
```

Even if I say `streamWriter.Write(source.toString());` it fails.

Funny thing is, that it works on one of the methods that calls this routine but not on any of the others.

And the order I call them in makes no difference either.

But regardless, even when I call the above, from the method that works, the output is still an empty MemoryStream.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't flush the stream writer so the word never gets written to the memory stream.

Add the following after the call to `streamWriter.Write`:

```
streamWriter.Flush();
```

Furthermore, if you want to read that word later from the memory stream, make sure to reset its position, because after the Write it is located after the word `slappy`:

```
memoryStream.Position = 0;
```

Comment: Also we can set [`AutoFlush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush.aspx) to true

Comment: +1. Side note: it may be better to return `new MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray())` (or based on the same buffer as original one) - properly disposing `streamWriter` will dispose `memoryStream` too...

Comment: Fantastic.  Is there any reason why when I have a 5k file, that it would write out 4k but not the last 1k.  That behavior was prior to using flush.  I there a tipping point where it does an AutoFlush?

Comment: The documentation of `AutoFlush` just states the following: "When AutoFlush is set to false, StreamWriter will do a limited amount of buffering". It looks like this "limited amount" is 1k in your case. So everytime there is more data in the internal buffer it flushes it and writes it to the stream, leading to the effect you have witnessed

Comment: Great.  Thanks.  Marking answered when I can.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to call `streamWriter.Flush();` you can set the AutoFlush-Property of the StreamWriter, at the moment you create it.

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream)
   {
      AutoFlush = true
   }
```

Comment: Yeah I got that too.  Going with the manual option for this solution as it makes a bit more sense.  +1 and thanks.