# MemoryStream Seek, Needed After Instance Creation With Buffer?

Tags: c#, memorystream

Do I need a `Seek` call in this code?

```
// Assume bytes = byte[] of some bytes
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(memoryStream);
}
```

Comment: Did you try removing it and seeing what happens? Seems like a question you could answer yourself.

Comment: It appears to work, but I am wondering if there are any edge case scenarios in which a `Seek` would be explicitly needed using the above code.

Comment: Since you have created a new `MemoryStream` object, its position will already be a the beginning of the stream. The `Seek` would only be needed if you needed to back up again later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to. For proving that, you can check the [constructor code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs#2873db25d2e326a6#references):

```
public MemoryStream(byte[] buffer, bool writable)
{
    if (buffer == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("buffer", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentNull_Buffer"));
    Contract.EndContractBlock();
    _buffer = buffer;
    _length = _capacity = buffer.Length;
    _writable = writable;
    _exposable = false;
    _origin = 0;
    _isOpen = true;
}
```

`Seek` changes `_position` (in your example to 0), which is not assigned in the constructor, so upon construction of the object `Position` will have the default `long` value of `0`.

It's a different story though if you perform further operations on the stream that could change its `Position` before reading from it.

Comment: Both answers were correct, but this one is the most informative for my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no need to `Seek` on stream that was just created.

You need to `Seek` or set [Position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.position(v=vs.110).aspx) is you wrote something to the stream before.

I.e. common question is "how to return `MemoryStream` with some serialized data" - you need to write data to the stream and than `Seek` to the beginning of the stream so `Read` will start from the beginning and not the last position of Write (hence always saying that there nothing left to read). Sample question - [Can't create MemoryStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140109/cant-create-memorystream/16140126#16140126).